# Julia:How to access an element in an array of a type based on the type field with specific value

Tags: types, julia, composite-types

I have an array of self defined type, called `links`, which its elements are of type `Link`.

```
type Link
    first::Int64
    second::Int64
    value::Array{Float64,1}
end
```

, and moreover for `links`, the `typeof(links)` is a `Vector{Link}`.

As you might have guessed, this is  part of a graph definition that I have, which  includes edges, and `first` refers to one endpoint and `second` refers to another endpoint. What I want to do is to select the `value` of a `link` in `links` where the the endpoint `first` is equal to a specific node number, let's call it `vertex_id`.
so in short I want the following:

`value of all those in links, whose .first == vertex_id`.

P.S, I know that for DataFrames of regular types, I can say

```
df[df[:col1] .== x,:col2]
```

But is there a similar way to do this for array of a self defined type?

Comment: I realized that I can do comprehensions:
`[x.value  for x in links if x.first == vertex_id]`
but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A list comprehension is indeed your best bet. It won't get much more concise, efficient, and elegant than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I can do comprehensions:

```
[x.value for x in links if x.first == vertex_id]
```

Answer (score 3):

`.` broadcasting syntax with: `getfield` would be another option (perhaps more analogous to what you can do with DataFrames):

`getfield.(links,[:value])[getfield.(links, [:first]).==vertex_id]`

But the list comprehension solution that you suggested is probably more elegant.

`[x.value for x in links if x.first == vertex_id]`